# Compiling lua scripts into a dll?

Tags: c++, dll, lua, luajit

I have heard of using LuaJIT to compile Lua code into bytecode and then into a static library.

Ideally I would want to be able to compile the Lua code into a dynamic library so I don't have to rebuild the main executable.

Can you compile Lua into a dll? If so how do you link it to c++ code since there's no headers? 
Finally how would you run the Lua scripts from inside the program?

Comment: "Ideally I would want to be able to compile the Lua code into a dynamic library so I don't have to rebuild the main executable." I don't understand how building Lua as a DLL has anything to do with rebuilding the main executable. How often are you recompiling the Lua *library*? Are you talking about the Lua interpreter or a Lua *script*?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you would do is link the lua interperter dll ( http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html ) to your program and then include the script as a resource such as in a header to your c/c++ program and use the lua.dll functions to execute it.  Also you can call lua functions from C using that method( this shows a several complete snippet examples with header files http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_c_calls_lua.htm ) .

Comment: Thanks but I still need to recompile the exe which defies the point I am trying to achieve

Comment: @DavidC Nothing says you have to keep it static and embedded in the executable, you can keep the script external and use a file read function to load it into memory then execute it with a lua function from the dll.